# cannot convert ‘Mypacket*’ to ‘const char*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘double atof(const char*)

Tags: c++

I am trying to do RSA encryption in omnet++ to encrypt the packet within a Vehicle1 node and then send encrypted packet to RA. But, I couldn't encrypt and send the packet to RA.
It shows error :

> cannot convert ‘Mypacket*’ to ‘const char*’ for argument ‘1’ to
> ‘double atof(const char*).

Here is my code :

```
    #include <sstream>
    #include<string.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<math.h>
    #include"Mypacket_m.h"
    #include <omnetpp.h>
    using namespace omnetpp;

    class Vehicle1: public cSimpleModule {
       cMessage *msg;
       virtual void initialize();
       virtual void handleMessage(cMessage *msg);
       int gcd(int a, int h);
       
   };

   Define_Module(Vehicle1);

      void Vehicle1::initialize()
      {

          Mypacket *pkt = new  Mypacket();

          scheduleAt(simTime() + dblrand(), msg->dup() );

      }

    void Vehicle1::handleMessage(cMessage *msg)
    {

        Mypacket *pkt = new Mypacket();
        //2 random prime numbers
         double m1;
         double p = 13;
          double q = 11;
          double n=p*q;//calculate n
          double track;
          double phi= (p-1)*(q-1);//calculate phi
         //public key
       //e stands for encrypt
         double e=7;
       
        while(e<phi) {
          track = gcd(e,phi);
          if(track==1)
          break;
          else
           e++;
      }
       //private key
       //d stands for decrypt
        //choosing d such that it satisfies d*e = 1 mod phi
         double d1=1/e;
         double d=fmod(d1,phi);
         double test2 = atof(pkt);
         double c = pow(test2,e); //encrypt the message
         double m = pow(c,d);
         c=fmod(c,n);
         m=fmod(m,n);
         cout<<"\n"<<"Encrypted message = "<<c;
        cModule *target;
       target=getParentModule()->getSubmodule("RA");
       sendDirect(c, target, "radioIn");
       scheduleAt(simTime() + dblrand(), msg->dup() );
       }
      int Vehicle1::gcd(int a, int b) {
      int t;
       while(1) {
            t= a%b;
            if(t==0)
             return b;
             a = b;
             b= t;
          }
        }
```

Thanks

Comment: `Mypacket *pkt = new Mypacket(); ... double test2 = atof(pkt);` - `pkt` is not a null-terminated `char*` string, hence the error. What are you trying to parse into a `double` exactly? And why are you not using an actual RSA library to handle this for you?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Sir, Thank you for your replay. Could you please provide any link of actual RSA library. packet Mypacket
{
double id = 9;
double RN = 123;
double lat = 11.80;
double lon = 76.00;
} This is my packet definition in .msg file of omnet++

Comment: asking for library recommendations is off-topic for StackOverflow